# Visual Studio 2019 not suggesting using statements, refactor option to add not suggested

Tags: visual-studio-2019

The following are images from my Home PC which is using the Community version of VS 2019 16.8.1, which shows how Visual Studio makes a suggestion to add "using System.IO;" when you try to use a FileInfo object without qualifying it.

[image]

If I click the menu option "Using System.IO" it adds the using statement (1) and the color of the FileInfo data type changes to light blue (on my default color scheme) to show that it recognizes FileInfo as a class.

[image]

However, on my work PC, which is VS 2019 Enterprise 16.7.3, it only gives me a tool top asking me if I am missing a reference, no lightning bolt suggestion and when I add the using myself, the text "FileInfo" does not change color as it does in (2) below. The program compiles an runs just fine. I can "Goto Definition" just fine and see the signature in the base class library.

Do you know what I have to do to be able to get the same behavior on my work PC as on my home pc? I have Roslynator 2019 extension installed on both, if that is relevant./

Comment: A technical wizard I know told me to try to reboot and what do you know-it worked! He always seems to have all the answers (um....same answer, but it fixes every problem)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact problem. It was a while after starting VS on a solution of mine, during a coding frenzy day. I read your question, your answer, and decided to try and simply close Visual Studio and open my solution again. It did the trick.